# How to send Column Name as parameter in Named Query

Tags: oracle, hibernate, named-query

I'm writing a Named query to fetch data's based on yearly bases.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM table1
   WHERE ((year1 > 0) OR (year2> 0 OR (beyondYear2> 0)));
```

The query is working fine. From `JSP` I'll be selecting the year, so for that particular year the record should load. The above query loads data for all the year range. Is there any way I can pass `Column Name` as parameter to avoid writing the query for every year?

```
SELECT * FROM table1
 WHERE ( :yearRange > 0);
```

**:yearRange** : as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parameter as a switch:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE ((year1 > 0 AND :yearRange='year1') OR (year2> 0 AND :yearRange='year2' OR (beyondYear2> 0 AND :yearRange='beyondYear2')));
```

Comment: How do I sent that from java? Should I use setString() or setParameter()? and I did not understand this part `:yearRange='year1'`

Comment: setParameter, its a normal query parameter

Comment: No. Its not working. I'm getting error saying : `SEVERE: Invalid column 
        name
        org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute 
        query`

Comment: Java code : `query = session.getNamedQuery("callTrafDataYear");
       query.setParameter("yearRange", "year1");`

Comment: Exception didn't mention the column name?

Comment: Thank you so much. :-) Its working. I had left out one column name while setting the property of a bean in hbm file.